# Cannot find Oauth in phpinfo()

Tags: php, oauth, php-extension

I downloaded the pre-compiled dll file from here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/, unziped it and copied the php_oauth.dll file to my php/ext folder, then add "extension=php_oauth.dll" to the php.ini. But I still can't find oauth in phpinfo(). Is there any step I missed? My OS is Windows7.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you reboot your web server?

Answer (score 2):

Please, verify if this module was properly loaded.

After you have copied the php_oauth.dll file to your php/ext folder, and then added "extension=php_oauth.dll" to the php.ini

do the following:

1. Open the windows command prompt (cmd.exe);
2. Type PHP -m and verify if everything is ok (oAuth was loaded sucessfully);
3. If something is wrong, example, "this is not a win32 valid application", you must download the correct version of php_oauth.dll file from this [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/) and deploy in the php/ext;
4. When you put the correct version and the command PHP -m show the oAuth library correctly loaded, restart your apache server.